# Import from DocumentDB to Azure Machine Learning - DateTime with milliseconds

Tags: r, azure, datetime, azure-machine-learning-service

I use the **Import** module from **Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML)** to get data from **DocumentDB**.

The import works fine.

---

In the **DocumentDB** **documents** are `DateTime` with `milliseconds`, like:

> "CurrentTime": "2017-07-17T20:18:55.757316"

and in **Azure ML** it is recognized as `DateTime-Feature` and it is shown like this:

> 2017-07-17T20:18:55

The problem is, that the `milliseconds` are missing.

I have tried to get the `milliseconds` with the **Edit Metadata** module, but it doesn't work for me. Additionally, I have tried to use **R** to convert the `CurrentTime` to **numeric**, like this:

```
time.milliseconds = as.numeric(dataset1[['CurrentTime']]);
print(time.milliseconds,digits=15)
```

But the `milliseconds` are still missing.

---

How can I get the **whole** `DateTime` with `milliseconds`?

---

**UPDATE:**

The complete **R** code:

```
options("digits.secs"=6)

dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame

time.milliseconds = as.numeric(dataset1[['CurrentTime']]);
dataset <- cbind(dataset1, time.milliseconds)

maml.mapOutputPort("dataset");
```

The result:

[image]

---

My suggestion is, that the **Import** module with **DocumentDB** doesn't support `milliseconds`!?

---

For now, I upload my `CurrentTime` as `milliseconds` from epoch to the **DocumentDB**. I hope there is a better way..

Comment: Note that 6 digits = microseconds. Milliseconds would be 3.  Also, I think if you look closely you'll see that you have 7 digits, which are 100 nanosecond unit, commonly called "ticks" in .NET.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that just because you have subsecond information in your data, doesn't mean that information is necessarily accurate or relevant.  One should decide that based on the *source* of the information.  For example, if it's just coming from a computer's clock, it depends on the accuracy and the precision of the computer's clock - which is usually not less than <10ms, but also consider clock-sync, etc.  Especially if the data is coming from different sources, I personally wouldn't trust anything under 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but I really think, that the problem is by the "Import" module. My workaround is, that I upload "CurrentTime" as milliseconds (Double) from epoch. Now, I can work with my data.

Comment: @MattJohnson: I need the CurrentTime to ordering my data. The interval of the data are over 10 ms (round about 100 - 200 ms), so it should be okay to use a normal DateTime!?

Comment: Sure, that should be ok.  Make sure you are using UTC time, not local time.

Answer (score 0):

You may need `options("digits.secs"=6)` (or at least three) to see them printed.  Witness:

```
R> options("digits.secs"=0)    ## suppresses sub-second display, default
R> Sys.time()
[1] "2017-07-18 07:22:00 CDT"
R> options("digits.secs"=6)    ## overrides default and forces six digits
R> Sys.time()
[1] "2017-07-18 07:22:05.161853 CDT"
R>
```

So chances are if the data is stored with subsecond precision as a datetime, then they should be imported with it too -- "you just don't see it" because of the default display granularity you need to override.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have tried this, but it doesn't work. I have updated my answer with the whole R code and the result.